# Macro to color alternating group of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA macro to color first 8 rows in an Excel sheet, then leave next 8 uncolored, then color 8 again - and so on till the end of the sheet.

So far I have the following code:

```
Sub ColorInGroups()

Dim k As Long
k = 1

For i = k To k + 7
     Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? You can achieve this with conditional formatting!

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted this as a macro, you could do the following:

```
Sub ColorInGroups()

Dim i As Long, w As Long

w = 8 ' Number of rows each time

For i = 1 To 50 * w Step w * 2           ' 50 will produce 50 groups of rows, increase/decrease as you like
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + w - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula in my code below, it will color the first 8 rows, then not color the next 8, and then color, and so on...

Note: You can change the Parameter `GroupSize` to the number of rows you want colored each time.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorInGroups()

Dim k As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim GroupSize As Long

k = 1
LastRow = 100
GroupSize = 8

For i = k To k + LastRow
    ' mathematical formula I used to get the result wanted
    If Round((i / GroupSize) + 0.5) Mod 2 <> 0 Then


    ' ***** mathematical formula (for flexible first row) *****
    'If (Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(((i - k) / GroupSize), 1) + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that does blocks of 7, 9, 7, 9, ... This function appears to work, using floor saves head-scratching of when to add 0.5 etc: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(((i - k) / GroupSize), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't assume that the first row is row 1, and uses pretty straight-forward syntax.

```
Sub ColorInGroups()
    ' Declare variables for which rows to colour, and what the block size should be
    Dim firstrow As Long: firstrow = 5
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = 35
    Dim groupsize As Long: groupsize = 8
    ' Loop over the rows chosen, and colour as desired
    Dim i As Long
    For i = firstrow To lastrow
        ' Check if i is within an "even" multiple block of groupsize
        If (i - firstrow) Mod groupsize * 2 >= groupsize Then
            Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

A more flexible option would be to pass a range into the sub, as well as the block size. Also resetting the colour to none for cells not in the grey block means you can re-run this sub without having to manually remove colours first.

```
Sub ColorInGroups(rng As Range, groupsize As Long)
    Dim firstrow As Long: firstrow = rng.Cells(1).Row
    Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = firstrow To lastrow
        ' Check if i is within an "even" multiple block of groupsize
        If (i - firstrow) Mod groupsize * 2 >= groupsize Then
            Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        Else
            Rows(i).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
' Pass in a range object and some integer
ColorInGroups ActiveSheet.UsedRange, 8
```

---

Lastly, this could be sped up by using

```
Sub ColorInGroups()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' ... sub code as above ...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is banding the 2nd group instead of the the first group of 8 rows.  You should probably qualify your cell references using `With rng.parent` to refer to Worksheet that `rng` belongs to.

Comment: Alright, note to users, use `<=` or `>` depending if you want to start with grey or white... And yes you should use `rng.Parent` to get the sheet, and always fully qualify ranges, but no answers here do because the objective of the question is the process not the implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

As @CodeConfident mentioned in his comment, you could use a formula and Conditional Formatting.

Have two conditional formats along the whole row and *using a formula to determine which cells to format*:
This formula (other formula are available and may be more efficient):
`=MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/8),2)=0` and `=MOD(INT((ROW()-1)/8),2)=1`

The *Format Painter* can then be used to copy the format down for however many rows you need.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting will improve reduce the file size and improve the speed and efficiency of the Workbook.

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),16)<8"
With Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

The problem with creating a large number of formatting blocks is that Excel has to create an xml node for each block to describe the formatting.

Notice the difference in file size after applying the formatting to the individual rows.

[image: Results]

Excel files are Zip folders.  By renaming the Workbook's extension to `Zip`, you can view the Worksheet's xml.  NOtice how there is a Node added for each row's formatting.

### [image]

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Seconds()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many seconds it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim FileLength As Long

    'Remember time when macro starts
    StartTime = Timer

    '*****************************
    FileLength = FileLen(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

    ApplyRowBanding

    '*****************************

    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    'Notify user in seconds
    Debug.Print "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds"

    Debug.Print "File Size Before Formatting:", FileLength

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    Debug.Print "File Size After Formatting:", FileLen(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

    Debug.Print "Difference in File Size:", FileLen(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - FileLength
End Sub

Sub ApplyRowBanding()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    For x = 1 To Rows.Count Step 16
        lastRow = IIf(x + 8 < Rows.Count, x + 7, Rows.Count - x)
        Rows(x & ":" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "*Conditional Formatting will  [...] improve the speed and efficiency of the Workbook*" is a very misleading sentence. Having many conditional formats over large areas in your workbook will significantly slow down re-calculation times during normal use of the workbook.

Comment: @Wolfie Applying the formats to only the used range would diffidently be a better approach.